# java bean \ object to android json object

Tags: android, json, serialization, reflection

I have an android application that relies heavily on Json Web Services.
so I have many requests and responses based on `json` format.
The basic idea is i have a request that get's a bean object, for example `HotelSearchData` and the request knows how to convert that bean to json map\ object then it writes that `JSONObject` to the network (using `http\https`).

naturally I need to convert from and to `json`.
For the time being I'm doing it in a bad but fast way:

1. get the `object`
2. have a list of const in the form of `KEY_XXXX` where `xxxx` is the name of the key and the value is the string that will be the actual key in the `json` object.
3. use the key like in the following example: `base.put(KEY_FROM_DATE, hotelSearchData.getFromDate())`
4. for ArrayList\ arrays I use `JSONArray` naturally, each `{}` in `json` is a bean object as far as I'm concerned and  I need to create a bean for it.

The problem is that this way, for future development is not so good (for the very least...)
Every new request requires me new beans that some of them may have the same information inside them causing information and code duplicity.

Every new request requires me to create new *KEY finals* copying sometimes from other request with similar keys - idiotic :-/

for the first item, except for optimizing what I'm about to do and dividing shared code beans to smaller items i can extend later on i can't see any elegant solution.

But for the requests\response I thought of something but I'm not so sure how elegant it is...
I know *Google* have a different json library that uses reflection to `serialize\deserialize` `JSONObject`s. I thought of using *annotations* and reflection to do the `serialization` and `deserialization`, the `annotation`s should help in the cases where the member name is **NOT** the same as the json key for the member's value. also for `ArrayList<?>` that it's type is not saved in byte code and so does not exist after compilation, so you can either specify basic type or full package name.

In this way once I create the bean with the help of some `annotations` (maybe `python` script \ant script to automate part of it ?) I can make beans that if tomorrow I move to `xml` or something else (`binary`) I can just create different `serializer`, `deserializer` and be done with it.

I hoped to hear your opinion on it, or some other solutions, get some inspiration, I'm really disappointed with my current code... :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you actually tried [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)? It will do the things you need, except the moving to XML/binary part, but you could probably abstract that in your code. Chances are that any XML serialization library might want to use different annotations, so it's not going to be automatic.

Comment: yes i did. but GSON don't use annotation for generic types, it wants you to give it the Class object of the array instead, and if your json key name is different from the member's name then , at least in the version i used, you can't have the key name changed using annotations. i guess i can try to contribute to GSON however i also heard criticism on it's performance.

Comment: Use the latest version. Using `@SerializedName` you can change the member's name to whatever you want. Gson also supports generic collections pretty well. As for performance, don't base your decision on hearsay, do a quick benchmark, and if it is _really slower_ than what you need, then you can consider something else.

Comment: 10x. i'll check it again then, however my boss decided toJson(JSONObject) should work nicely as we don['t plan on moving to anything else in the near future, i find it problematic from stigmatization point of view and the fact i still need to write down all the keys...